# HashMap: It displays minimum value in TextView but min_variable has more values

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm trying to make some instructions when there will be appropriate minimum integer value. For example: when variable "round_min" = 10 -> there are some instructions. When "round_min" = 100 -> there is another instruction.

I try to implement function which finds minimum value in HashMap.
For example: I have two elements in HashMap. And there is finding minimum value, and it's displaying in TextView properly.

But when I want to use this variable "round_min" to another function there are displaying all values in hashmap. I want to have always the minimum.

Below I present code:

```
int round_min;

// nearestDistances is a hashmap where I put distances
Map.Entry<String, Float> nearestMarker = null;

for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : nearestDistances.entrySet()) {    
    if (nearestMarker == null || nearestMarker.getValue() > entry.getValue()) {
        nearestMarker = entry;
        round_min = Math.round(nearestMarker.getValue());
        Log.e(" MIN ", round_min + "");

        // it displays in log.e all values 

        // this function see all values, not only minimum
        DisplayMinimumValue(getApplicationContext(), round_min); 
        Log.e("    ROUND MIN    ", round_min + "");

        tvDistanceToNearest.setText(String.valueOf(round_min)); // there is displaying only minimum value
    }
}
```

Could someone help me to find the problem and how to figure out with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move all the lines

```
// this function see all values, not only minimum
    DisplayMinimumValue(getApplicationContext(), round_min); 
    Log.e("    ROUND MIN    ", round_min + "");

    tvDistanceToNearest.setText(String.valueOf(round_min)); // there is   displaying only minimum value
```

at the end, after second } so that you are outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Since i can't comment yet... i'm unsure what your question is. I see that you are updating your round_min variable if you encounter a smaller value in the map. I also see that you have some methods that use that variable inside your iteration. What part of the program is not acting like you want it to?

Comment: When I use method: "DisplayMinimumValue(context, round_min) it shows me all values in the hashmap. I cannot understand why it can't show only the minimum value. But when I use tvDistanceToNearest (TextView) in my application it shows only the minimum value in textView. I would like to achieve that when I put "round_min" to above method there will be only one minum value. Now there are put all values from hashmap. How to fix it?

Comment: DisplayMinimumValue is used inside your loop, it will display ever value min_round is assigned to, so every time it's updated. If you want to just display the final min value you'll have to call that outside the loop.

Comment: Yes it helped. But I can only mark one correct answer. Thank you to you for help too. Regards :)

Comment: didn't realize that Ben already had the answer hidden in this comment, when I added my answer. Therefore, +1 from me for the "answer", where the solution was somehow hidden in the comments ;)